# Change first-child css on parent hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

The fiddle of the sample is here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/3cYtX/12/

I have an element representing an image (say, video image screen) and a child element representing another image (say 90x60, the "play" icon).

```
<div class="big">
    <img class="small">
</div>
```

[image]

The small image is centered vertically and horizontally.

I want when I over the *big* image the *small* one change its opacity.

The code bellow works **only** when I hover the *small* image.

```
.small {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.small:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Is there a way to fix that (change on hover the *big* image) *only* via CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this :

```
.big:hover .small{

  // do stuff
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3cYtX/14/)

Note: I'm using `div` instead of `img` element here.

Answer (score 0):

```
.big {
    width:200px;
    height:150px;
    background-color: green;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.small {
    opacity: 0.9;
    background: red;
    width:90px;
    height:60px;
}
.big:hover > .small {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/3cYtX/13/)**